# Issue when restricting number of order_items to order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm building a store in Rails that has a specific sales model. I need to allow a user to add only 3 items to his order per 30 days. The 30 days counter should start upon adding the first order_item. Once 30 days expires, user would be able to add 3 orders. If 30 days didn't pass and for an example, user adds two order_items he would still be allowed to add one more order_item within 30 days. So as well if user tries to add more then 3 items to show an error message and disregard saving of the order_items to current_user's order.

So what I did:
I added a begin_date and a order_counter to user model. Every time I add an order, to look if the begin_date is more than 30 days ago, then set the begin_date to the actual date. If the begin_date is less than 30 days ago, to increase the counter. And if the counter is already 3 refuse the order.

The issue:
I can see that Order_Counter is staying at number 3 in my rails admin. However, I'm still able to add unlimited order_items to user's order.
What did do wrong?

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
 def create
    now = Date.today
  if current_user.begin_date && ((now - 30) < current_user.begin_date)
     if current_user.order_counter >= 3
        redirect_to root_path
     else
       current_user.order_counter += 1
       current_user.save
     end
  else 
    current_user.order_counter = 1
    current_user.begin_date = now
    current_user.save
  end


  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { flash[:notice] = "ORDER HAS BEEN CREATED." } 
  end

@order = current_order
  @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
  @order.user_id = current_user.id
  @order.save
  session[:order_id] = @order.id


end
```

order_item.rb

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :order

  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
  validate :product_present
  validate :order_present


  before_save :finalize

  def unit_price
    if persisted?
      self[:unit_price]
    else
      product.price
    end
  end

  def total_price
    unit_price * quantity
  end

private
  def product_present
    if product.nil?
      errors.add(:product, "is not valid or is not active.")
    end
  end

  def order_present
    if order.nil?
      errors.add(:order, "is not a valid order.")
    end
  end

  def finalize
    self[:unit_price] = unit_price
    self[:total_price] = quantity * self[:unit_price]
  end


end
```

order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order_status
  has_many :order_items
  before_create :set_order_status
  before_save :update_subtotal

  def subtotal
    order_items.collect { |oi| oi.valid? ? (oi.quantity * oi.unit_price) : 0 }.sum
  end
private
  def set_order_status
    self.order_status_id = 1
  end

  def update_subtotal
    self[:subtotal] = subtotal
  end
end
```

Comment: When do user create new orders? 
Do they have the same order over a 30 day period?

Comment: Hmm... it is created on each new session. New order per new session per each user. So I guess probably solution would be to restrict number of orders per user for 30 days to one... How can I restrict one order per 30 days?

Comment: If I go to your store on day 1, I create an order - add 2 items.

When would I get back to add the last item I can before the 30 day limit?
And would I add it to the same order?

Comment: The issue is if you for example add 2 items now, log out, and sign in again, and then add a new order_item, new order is created. Last order(the one you added two order_items) is still saved to database.

Comment: Okay, so no matter the count of orders I do in a month, what is needed to be restricted is the order_items?

Comment: Essentially yes, but now I realize if I also don't restrict the count of orders then user can add unlimited order_items?.. But anyway, currently even if we are within the same session and adding order_items to same order I'm still able to add unlimited order_items...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115709/discussion-between-davidwessman-and-marko-i).